# Check if object instantiated

Tags: c#, .net, instantiation

I have an object which is made of many other objects! I am trying to find the value of of one of the properties (an enum) but can't.

Now, normally if I want to check if an object is null I can do

```
if (object == null)
```

but this results in the same error.

I tried

```
if (object.Equals(null)) and the same error.
```

The error message I'm getting is objectName threw exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

I'm trying to determine if my object is instantiated or not. Now, I can stick this into a try catch, if it errors then I know it's not, but to me this feels very wrong (although I may not have a choice).

The other problem I have is this project isn't mine and is a black box to everyone and so I can't make any changes to the original object! This means, all I have is what I have got, an object which may or may not be instantiated and I need a way of telling.

Other than the try catch, do I have any other options?

**EDIT**

So, the object is

```
public partial class SaveBundleResponse 
{
    SaveBundleResponseHeader header;
}

public partial class SaveBundleResponseHeader 
{      
        private SaveBundleResponseHeaderStatus status;
}

public enum SaveBundleResponseHeaderStatus 
{        
        Success, Fail, OK, OtherStates
}
```

So the SaveBundleResponse is created initially, the instance is then passed through a 'workflow' style environment and each property becomes 'populated/updated' etc as it goes deeper into the workflow. However, in a few situations, the enum is never set.

The problem is, I need to know the value of the enum (or if it is null).

The code I am trying to use is

```
        if (saveBundleResponse.Header.Status // what ever happens, it fails at this point as Status is not initiated.
```

Comment: Can you provide your real code? Where is enum?

Comment: `if (myObject != null)` is the correct way to check if an object is instatiated. Maybe you are calling a method of the object, that then uses a field that is not instantiated - and hence the exception?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide at least a prototype of the container object you're having trouble with, and preferably the sub-objects it contains as well.  Right now there are a number of things that could be causing this problem.

Comment: Dave, could you please post full code. You are doing something wrong. If object is null, (object == null) should be true and not throw any exceptions.

Comment: An enumeration cannot be `null` - probably it is `header` that is `null` in some cases.

Comment: Either saveBundleResponse or .Header is null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (saveBundleResponse != null)
{
    var header = saveBundleResponse.Header;
    if (header != null)
    {
        var status = header.Status;
    }
}
```

Comment: can header be null? enum is not a nullable type, so it should be initiated to the default value, which in his case will be 0? i have not used C# in a while, so forgive me if it does not make sense

Comment: @Alex sure header can be null. It's a reference type. And default value of enum object is `(EnumType)0`.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. My object was instantiated, but my property (of which used had it's own property of the enum) wasn't instantiated. Thank you for taking the time and helping.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
SaveBundleResponse sbr = ...;
if (sbr.Header != null && !sbr.IsDisposed)
{
    //Do the work
}
```

This should work (if the class is not a control you can't use the IsDisposed check).